# How to run a Square array using only iterator while and array

Tags: arrays, square

```
def square_array(array)

     new_array = []

end
```

method, square_array, that squares each element in an array of numbers and returns a new array of these squared numbers. using while

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function square_array(arr) {
  const squaredArr = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    squaredArr.push(arr[i] * arr[i]);
    i++;
  }
  return squaredArr;
}

console.log(square_array(arr));
```